# how to fetch data from xml document and write to a text file?

Tags: c#

```
namespace readtask
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Process.Start(@"E:\SAMPLE PROJECTS\TaskName.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what you have tried so far?? let us know, and we will guide what you have done wrong. the above doesn't seems to be related to your problem statement.

Comment: Did you even google about "How to read xml file in C#"? Or you want us to do that?

Comment: i can read a xml  document..from that document i need information           eg:<html> <titile>stddetails</title>   <name>athul</name>   ..from this i want to fetch name:athul to a note pad .For that what should i do...i am a begginer

Comment: i am using via windows form application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are one to many ways to achieve this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class SampleXML
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    //Create the XmlDocument.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("TaskName.xml");

    //Display the desired tag.
    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("name");
    for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {   
      Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
    }  

  }
}
```

[or this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604330/xml-parsing-read-a-simple-xml-file-and-retrieve-values)

[or maybe this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605396/c-sharp-get-xml-tag-value)

[definitely look at this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files?rq=1)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

-<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task" version="1.2">


-<RegistrationInfo>

<Description>My first task scheduler</Description>

<URI>\TaskName</URI>

</RegistrationInfo>


-<Triggers>


-<CalendarTrigger>

<StartBoundary>2018-05-03T03:37:14</StartBoundary>

<Enabled>true</Enabled>


-<ScheduleByMonth>


-<DaysOfMonth>

<Day>8</Day>

</DaysOfMonth>


-<Months>

<September/>

</Months>

</ScheduleByMonth>

</CalendarTrigger>

</Triggers>      THIS IS MY XML FILE

Comment: okay but you mentioned a different tag in the comments section, replace the `doc.GetElementsByTagName("name");` with any oter tag name

Comment: I am using windows form application..then how i can use console.write function??   i used one button function am writing inside it